# Move middleware code from app.js to it's own function and file

Tags: reactjs, jwt, middleware, next.js

In my app.js file I have some middleware for authentication like this:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const jwtSecret = "mysuperdupersecret"; // actually in .env file

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.path == "/api/login") {
    return next();
  }

  const token = req.headers.authorization;


  try {
    var decoded = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret);
    console.log("decoded", decoded);
  } catch (err) {
    // Catch the JWT Expired or Invalid errors
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: err.message });
  }

  next();
});
```

I have created a middleware folder and put a file called 'auth.js' inside of it. Then placed this code in it:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const jwtSecret = "mysuperdupersecret";

function auth(req, res, next) {
  if (req.path == "/api/login") {
    return next();
  }

  const token = req.headers.authorization;


  try {
    var decoded = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret);
    console.log("decoded", decoded);
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: err.message });
  }
}

module.exports = auth;
```

Before I did this my application was working. Now I get a 500 internal server error; message":"jwt is not defined"

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// CORS middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // Allow Origins
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  // Allow Methods
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  // Allow Headers
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization"
  );
  // Handle preflight, it must return 200
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    // Stop the middleware chain
    return res.status(200).end();
  }
  // Next middleware
  next();
});

// Routes
app.get("/api/login", (req, res) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ username: "test" }, jwtSecret, { expiresIn: 60 }); // 1 min token
  res.json({ token: token });
});

app.get("/api/token/ping", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ msg: "all good mate" });
});

app.get("/api/ping", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ msg: "pong" });
});

module.exports = app;
```

How do I get it to work again?

Comment: show the updated app.js too

Comment: You are still referring to `jwt` in `app.js`, too, but you've deleted the import. Also you don't actually seem to be using `auth.js` in `app.js`

Comment: But I importing them in auth.js. Am I meant to include auth.js in app.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `/app/login` route, you are using the `jwt` module without importing it in `app.js` also the `jwtSecret` is also not inside app.js now.

I also cannot see how you have used the `auth.js` you had created in the app

You could update the auth.js as

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const jwtSecret = "mysuperdupersecret";

function auth(req, res, next) {
  if (req.path == "/api/login") { // check for HTTP GET/POST if required
    const token = jwt.sign({ username: "test" }, jwtSecret, { expiresIn: 60 }); // 1 min token
    res.json({ token: token });
  }
  else {
    const token = req.headers.authorization;
    try {
      var decoded = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret);
      console.log("decoded", decoded);
      next();
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({ msg: err.message });
    }
  }
}
```

in app.js

```
/*.
.
. other code
*/
const auth = require('./auth.js');

app.use(auth);

/*.
. remaining code
.
*/
```

Comment: But I importing them in auth.js. Am I meant to include auth.js in app.js?

Comment: as far as app.js is concerned, you are not importing anything from auth.js Its presence is not known to your application in any way :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I updated my code but still getting the 500 server error?

Comment: same error ?
can you update teh question with the new code ?

Comment: I left auth.js as is and just changed app.js to have `const auth = require("./middleware/auth");  app.use(auth);`

Comment: It still doesn't import jwt to your app.js!! If you want to use a variable in a js file there should be a reference to it. You could move the login to inside auth.js like the answer above to fix the issue

OR you could import jwt and jwtSecret to app.js too.

Comment: Okay, but I don't understand why I have to import it twice? Into auth.js and into app.js. That is the part that is confusing me. I thought if I am importing into auth.js and using auth.js in app.js then that is fine? Because the first line in auth.js is `const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");`

Comment: you can't get the dependencies unless you explicitly export and import between modules. Otherwise, each of these dependencies should be using multiple other dependencies internally and the namespace cannot be managed!

Comment: you are importing into auth.js but not exporting it. So its variable scope is limited. It is said to have the module scope. It cannot be accessed from outside the module unless it is exported from the module and imported in another module where it is needed,

Comment: Okay, so it is pretty pointless importing it into auth.js and I should rather only import it in app.js?

Comment: you have to import it in auth.js too since you are using it inside the function which checks for the user authorization headers. Basically, you have to have them imported to the scope where it is being executed.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks for your patience!